# Method call inside save() display return on template before form submission

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates

My django model contains these fields:

```
nod_id1 = models.ForeignKey('Eonodes',..)
nod_id2 = models.ForeignKey('Eonodes',..)
```

that are rendered like dropdown lists as expected.

In my models.py I override the save method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_direction_descr(self.nod_id1.id, self.nod_id2.id)
        super(Webrequests, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

where

```
def get_direction_descr(nod_id1, nod_id2):
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          cursor.execute("SELECT GetDirectionDescr("+str(nod_id1)+","+str(nod_id2)+") from sys.dual")
          result = cursor.fetchall()
          return result[0][0]
```

Is there a way what `get_direction_descr()` returns to be displayed on the template on the fly just after the user selects nod_id1 and nod_id2 from a dropdown list before the form is submitted?
Or how I could accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can move method get_direction_descr to a model. Than you should use ajax on change event when select list(first or second) is changed and pull info to your template.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?what do u mean by saying 'move method get_direction_descr' to a model? and as far as the lists are concerned, they're rendered through foreignKey field in modelForms. How will i treat them as the usual select fields since I can't have the id for each choice?Sry if my questions seem dumb, but I'm new to all that and pretty stuck right now.